Php - imagick extension installation error on MacOS Sonoma
I  recently switched to macOS and started a simple project that will require me to use the Imagick extension. I'm trying to install Imagick using Homebrew but encountered an error during installation.
I already executed the following command.
pecl install imagick

git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick
cd imagick
phpize && ./configure
make
make install

However, I'm encountering an error on make install command.
mkdir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl: File exists
mkdir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1


Also tried removing existing pecl directory and reinstalling imagick.
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl
sudo mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl
pecl install imagick


But encountered this error
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl/20230831/imagick.so'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl/20230831

I tried searching for the same error but couldn't find any.
How to fix this issue? How do I find this directory on my mac(still familiarizing myself with apple ecosystem)?

A similary error appears with me, when I run :
pecl install xdebug

It appears like this:
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl/20230831/xdebug.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8/pecl/20230831

when find :
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.8
> pecl -> /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl

there is a Symbolic Link.
So we need just run by ourselves to make the dir:
mkdir /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl

then install and make install  again, Succeed!
